# Swapoff doesnt work with cron

Tags: cron

I have this **test** script:

```
root@PC:~# cat /usr/wsh/swap_reload.sh
# Swap clear
# 03.08.2017
swapoff -a ;
swapon /tmp/swap

root@PCA73:~# ls -l /usr/wsh/swap_reload.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 94 авг 10 16:24 /usr/wsh/swap_reload.sh
```

Also i added cron task (root cron):

```
* * * * * /usr/wsh/swap_reload.sh
```

But when i every 5 minutes look at `free` - it is not changing(
But should flush allocated swap for every minute, isnt it?

```
root@PCA73:~# free -h
                   total        used        free      shared  buff/cache     
available Mem:     31G          921M        3,9G         16G      26G 
13G Swap:           99M          47M         52M
```

Why doesnt it work?

Comment: Do you see it change if you run the script manually?

Comment: Yes, it does. Problem occures only in cron :(
So i even tried to add symlink to `/etc/cron.hourly/ ` - no result :(

Comment: Try this: use full paths: `/sbin/swapon` and `/sbin/swapoff`.

Answer (score 1):

Your script doesn't have a shebang line

```
#!/bin/sh
...
```

Without that line the script can only be run from a shell and 
that shell will *guess* that the script is to be executed
as a shell script. Basically the order is as follows:

- the shell tries to execute the script as a binary and 
  the kernel may or may not look for a magic number 
  (with `#!` counting as magic number)
- if that doesn't work then the shell executes the script as
  a shell script.

That's why it works when you invoke the script from a shell
even though it lacks the shebang line.

If you run the script from cron, then there is no *parent shell*
that could guess how to execute the script. To avoid this, add a
*shebang* line like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Swap clear
# 03.08.2017
swapoff -a ;
swapon /tmp/swap
```

Further reading:

- [Shell script working fine without shebang line? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296783/5830574) (Question on SO)
- [*Section - Why do some scripts start with #! ... ?*](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html)

Comment: As an alternative, `sh <script>` can be issued. However, adding shebang should be preferred as it remains with the script.